# I am building an electron app and I am trying to ensure that if one url is unavailable a second one is attempted before my default error page

Tags: node.js, electron

I am building an electron app and I am trying to ensure that if one url is unavailable a second one is attempted before my default error page. It works with one just fine. It works with one just fine. I would appreciate help getting this if else statement correct.

```
''' wc2.once('did-finish-load'  ,  () => {
if(childWindow.loadURL(appConfig['websiteUrl2'])){}
else {
    childWindow.loadURL(appConfig['websiteUrl3'])
}
})'''
```

Comment: By unavailable do you mean if the page didn't respond?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once `websiteUrl2` has failed to load this code will load `websiteUrl3` and if that url fails then you can load your error screen.

Here I'm using the `did-fail-load` event to detect if a url is unavailable.

```
wc2.once('did-fail-load', function (evt, errorCode, errorDescription, pageUrl) {
    if (pageUrl == appConfig['websiteUrl2']) { // If first page fails load second page.
        childWindow.loadURL(appConfig['websiteUrl3'])
    } else if (pageUrl == appConfig['websiteUrl3']) { // If both urls fail load default error screen.
        // Load your default error screen here.
    }
});
```

[See docs for: `did-fail-load`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#event-did-fail-load)

Comment: @EricPettway Awesome, don't forget to [accept my answer when you're ready](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

`loadUrl` is an asynchronous method. It returns immediately and returns a promise. So you have to await the result like this:

```
wc2.once('did-finish-load', async () => {
    try {
        await childWindow.loadURL(appConfig['websiteUrl2'])
    } catch (firstFailed) {
        try {
            await childWindow.loadURL(appConfig['websiteUrl3'])
        } catch (secondFailed) {
            console.error('Couldn\'t load any page');
        }
    }
});
```

See here: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winloadurlurl-options